# Where can I find a scanner icon?

Tags: icons

I just installed VueScan and I need the path to a scanner icon that I can add to my .desktop file, so that there isn't a blank square in my Launcher panel. I have been unable to find anything in /usr/share/icons

Comment: There are "scanner" and "scan" icons in the folder Humanity and gnome both in /usr/share/icons/, also you can create your own, download one to any location and add the path to your .desktop file, etc.

Comment: Try `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/devices/scanner-symbolic.svg`. It's not pretty, but it should do.

Answer (score 3):

To add a scanner icon to your `.desktop` file you may add the following line:

```
Icon=scanner
```

This will render the default scanner icon (depending on your theme):

[image]

<sup>Shown for default 12.04 Unity/GNOME</sup>

To add a custom icon replace this line by:

```
Icon=/full/path/to/icon
```